# ¿Porqué al poner un número con decimal el código si queda en el bucle?

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.*; 

public class money_eu
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
        BufferedReader Input=new BufferedReader (reader);

        double dinero = 0.0F;
        double resultado = 0.0F;


        String europa = Input.readLine(); 
        dinero = Double.parseDouble(europa);

        while ( dinero < 0 )
        {
            System.out.println("Error, no es posible un numero negativo ");
            String europa1 = Input.readLine(); 
            dinero = Float.parseFloat(europa1);
        }

        resultado = dinero; //para trabajar con sola una variable
        while ( resultado != 0 )
        {            
            if ( resultado - 500.0 >= 0  && resultado >= 500.0 ) //500€
            {
                resultado = resultado - 500.0;
                a++;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( resultado - 200.0 >= 0  && resultado >= 200.0 ) //200€
                {
                    resultado = resultado - 200.0;
                    b++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( resultado - 100.0 >= 0  && resultado >= 100.0 ) //100€
                    {
                        resultado = resultado - 100.0;
                        c++;
                    }

            }

        }
   }
```

Quiero que al poner *342.78* salga todo bien. Al final me va decir cuántos billetes y monedas que hay fueron usados. Cuando introduzco un número entero sale de bucle bien, pero cuando es numero con decimales no me va. Queda dentro del bucle y no sale nada al final. ¿Alguien podría decirme lo que esta mal ahí? Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: El problema es la condición de salida del bucle. Tienes comprobación de resultado !=0. Si pones un decimal, y empiezas a restar enteros, nunca llegará a ser igual a 0 ni saldrá del bucle. Puedes empezar cambiando la comprobación a resultado >0

Comment: @Jakala, Hola, hago este cambio resultado > 0 y también resultado > 0.0, resultado > 00.00 . Pero, con números con decimales sigue igual :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo operaciones de coma flotante, vas a tener problemas con la exactitud.
Si utilizas "double", 0.03-0.02 no es igual a 0.01 es igual a 0.009999999999999998

Sin embargo, otros valores como 0.05, no causan ese problema.

Haz la prueba:

```
Double x=0.07,y=0.02;
System.out.println(x-y);
//El resultado es 0.05

Double x=0.03,y=0.02;
System.out.println(x-y);
//El resultado es 0.009999999999999998
```

Con la clase BigDecimal, esto no ocurre:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.03");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.02");
System.out.println("Resta= " + a.subtract(b));
//El resultado es 0.01
```

Otra cuestion es que para un ejercicio de clase, utilizar la clase BigDecimal se escape de aquello que se te pide.

---

Tambien puedes hacerlo con céntimos en vez de decimales, así no tendrás problemas con doubles ni con conversiones que de momento puede que sean más complejas de manejar.

Ejemplo con 1200 euros:

```
double dinero = 1200.0;
int resultado = (int) (dinero * 100); //multiplicamos dinero por 100 para obtener los céntimos (120000)
```

Para pasar el double a int, le hemos realizado un "casting", una "conversión". Si aún no lo utilizas, lo utilizarás, es algo básico y muy habitual.

Ahora hacemos las comprobaciones y si corresponde, las impresiones por pantalla
Si resultado es mayor de 500 euros (en céntimos 50000)

```
if (resultado >= 50000){
//imprimimos 120000/50000 que da la cantidad de billetes de quinientos que hay en 1200 euros (2)
System.out.println("Billetes de 500 euros: " + resultado / 50000);
resultado %= 50000;// esto devolverá los céntimos que quedan, en este caso, 20000 (200 euros)
}
```

Ahora tendríamos que añadir el resto de comprobaciones que queremos realizar, con los billetes y monedas de 200, 100, 50, etc, todo en céntimos (20000, 10000, 5000...), que básicamente es copia/pega del if anterior, adaptándolo a las cantidades correspondientes, teniendo mucho cuidado al escribir las cantidades en céntimos de euro

Creo que esto es más simple que utilizar conversiones.

Comment: Voy intentar pasar todo a BigDecimal. Y preguntar si puedo usar en este trabalho.

Comment: Tambien puedes hacerlo con double, pero deberías utilizar el operador %, lo que te obliga a revisar todo el ejercicio. Uno de los problemas (y ventaja) con los que te encontrarás programando, es que las cosas no se hacen únicamente de una forma, sino que hay infinidad de métodos para obtener el mismo resultado. Que el profesor te oriente de que es lo más adecuado a tu nivel actual.

Comment: Uso el BigDecimal pero mi resultado aún no sale del bucle, pongo 342.78 y me queda parado en 0.03. ¿Sabe decirme porque eso ocurre?

Comment: No acabo de verlo tampoco, tambien es verdad que me llego a perder con tanto if else. Échale un vistazo a la edición que he hecho de la respuesta, a ver si te puede ayudar más realizarlo desde otro punto de vista.

Comment: Me has salvado y abierto los horizontes, ahora si está bien y comprendo mejor como va. Gracias <3